# What does "stand back and stand by" mean

Tags: phrase-usage

I understand that "stand back and stand by" means leave, stay off the way and stay there.

But by reaction of media I suspect that this is not exactly correct? In context of recent (2020) US presidential debate.

Comment: Two of the phrases are different and the meanings you mentioned are not the meanings of the phrasal verbs.

Comment: Can you mention the source or might be write the whole sentence where you read those phrases?

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh You should be able to guess the source.https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/w172x2yx9fcxw69

Comment: @DJClayworth I am not a native American. Nor am I interested in politics. Hence the source was unknown to me. Thanks anyways. I would listen to the heated debate.

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh For your own sanity, please don't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**"Stand back", when used metaphorically, means to disengage**, or to allow events to take their course. A doctor, arriving at the scene of an accident might tell passers by to "stand back", meaning not just literally backing away from the victim but also to stop taking action and allow the doctor to work unimpeded.

**"Stand by" means to be ready to take some action.** If soldiers are told to "stand by" they will make ready. The expectation is that an order for action will be given soon. Slightly differently, if the soldiers report that their attack target is in sight, if told to "stand by" will not attack, but will stay ready to attack.

Both are completely different from "stand down", which means to cease action. Soldiers told to "stand down" stop fighting and carries no implication of maintaining readiness.

As is usual what the President of the United States actually meant is anybody's guess. The Proud Boys (who are violent right wing extremists) absolutely took "stand by" as meaning "wait for the call to action".

Answer (score 2):

I agree that "stand by" means "wait in readiness", and typically that means that action will soon be triggered by an order.  Sometimes with news broadcasts, the term "stand by" means "wait because some important news is coming in."

Answer (score 1):

The context here is the 2020 first US Presidential debate, in which Pres. Trump was asked to denounce militant white nationalist groups who have promised violence to guarantee his reelection (or in retaliation if he isn’t re-elected). He refused to denounce those groups and instead told them to “stand back and stand by.”

In a military context, the meaning of “stand back” is to *stay back*, and the meaning of “stand by” is to *stay ready to act on further orders*.

Trump’s representatives claim that isn’t what he meant, but that is almost certainly how those groups have interpreted it.

Answer (score 1):

"Stand by," by itself, can have multiple meanings.  To stand by can mean "to do nothing."  Indeed, it would be a common phrase to state that someone "stood by and did nothing" (a bit of a tautology), especially in contexts where the person could have taken some action that the speaker believes would have been proper.  However, as an imperative, an instruction to "stand by" almost always carries the connotation of readiness, doing nothing at the moment but being prepared to take action when instructed.

"Stand back" has been well explained by DJClayworth, above.

The two phrases are not usually put together in this way.  Like many of Donald Trump's public statements, the meaning is not clear.  This is what Trump said when he was asked to demand that white supremacists and militias "stand down," with an intended meaning that was also explained by DJClayworth.  It's entirely possible that Trump really meant to tell the groups to "stand down."  If so, this is exactly the kind of error Trump made recently when, intending to discuss "herd immunity," he referred to a "herd mentality."  But Trump never acknowledges an error; this is the man who insisted "covfefe" had some hidden meaning when he most likely fell asleep on his keyboard.  So by refusing to address the contents of his previous statements, Trump has allowed the Proud Boys to seize on the "readiness" implications of "stand by," and the media has largely followed that narrative.

Answer (score 0):

Stand back and stand by: can't be separated in the statement of Donald Trump; he meant be prepared to do what I'll ask you to do.